# C# UWP XAML Animations

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, winrt-xaml, uwp

I have a Page with a Grid containing two columns, the first contains a button which toggles the visibility of the second (via a ViewModel binding). How can I add an animation for showing/hiding the second column (with Pivot as content) to this scenario?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Button Command="{Binding TogglePivot}"/>
    </Grid>

    <Pivot x:Name="Content_Pivot" Grid.Column="1">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <!-- Hidden state -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content_Pivot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!-- Visible state -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Visible">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content_Pivot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="600"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <!-- Show -->
            <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="True">
                <core:GoToStateAction StateName="Visible"/>
            </core:DataTriggerBehavior>

            <!-- Hide -->
            <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="False">
                <core:GoToStateAction StateName="Hidden" />
            </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <!-- Content.. -->
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

The above works fine, but **only on the first toggle** of the visibility of the Pivot. Subsequent toggles do not show the animation..

Any easy way of achieving this without manually invoking Storyboards?

Thanks.

**==EDIT==**

I made some changes to above code (namely, added `VisualStates` and `DataTriggerBehaviour`).

Still can't get it to work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a similar scenario what I did was not toggle the visibility of the pivot but rather the width of the grid column (or the pivot). After all a pivot with zero width is invisible. 
Plus from what I can see in your code the size of the second column is set to 300 so the target width for the animation won't be a problem.

My suggestion is to create two storyboards in xaml targeting the width of the pivot. The first would expand it and the second would collapse it. Then use  DataTriggerBehavior bound to the TogglePivot to trigger the storyboards. This way the xaml is still clean and no code is required.

If you try it and can't get it right I can provide some sample code.

Edit: You got the idea a little bit wrong. This is what worked for me.

```
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
<Page.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Name="PaneStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="300" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content_Pivot" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Name="CloseStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content_Pivot" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
    </Storyboard>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">                
            <Button Content="Opend and Close" Command="{Binding TogglePivot}" />
        </Grid>

        <Pivot x:Name="Content_Pivot" Grid.Column="1" Width="300" Background="Blue">

            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

             <!--Show--> 

                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="True">
                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource PaneStoryboard}"/>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>


             <!--Hide-->

                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="False">
                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseStoryboard}"/>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <!-- Content.. -->
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks @Corcus, I've updated my OP with my attempt... Still no dice. Do you mind showing me your sample?

Comment: I'll update my answer when I get to my home pc. Stay tuned :)

Comment: @Ubobo You had got the idea a bit wrong. I updated my answer. What you needed were double animations and not key frame. Also use of the visual state manager was not necessary.

Comment: Don't ever animate the `Width`. It's a *Dependent Animation* which will likely give you performance issues.

Comment: @Justin XL I agree with you in principle. I try to avoid it too. However, when I have to achieve the effect mentioned in the question for a single element I have not encountered any performance issues. If there is a more performant way to do the same I'd like to know it and use it too.

Comment: You rarely just animate one single element. In this case, if either panel has complex layout, the performance will be affected. Alternatively, you can animate the TranslateX of both panels. You will need to manually calculate the other panels TranslateX whenever the width of the page changes.